# html: remove space between ordered list and the line before

Tags: html, html-lists

want to implement an automated e-mail in pentaho. Therefore I want to use HTML in the body.

**Issue**
Want to remove space between a line (it's kind of a header) and the succeeding ordered list.

**Tried**
padding: 0
margin: 0
Tried it with "lh" as well. 
The space disappeared but the line break disappeared as well.

```
<style>
</style>

<font color="red">
<u>FAILED</u>
</font>
<ol type="1">
<li>first</li>
<li>second</li>
</ol>
```

**Output**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZlGz.png
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using all the 'String Operation' step options ?

Comment: No, I did not. Never worked with them before btw.